# Excel - Vlook up with Imported data

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel work book I have 2 tabs.
1 has imported data from another workbook.
The other I am attempting to do a vlookup, to fill in some cells based on the data in the first workbook.
However, the vlook up is not working, until I look at the imported data, select the cell and hit enter. The data in the first worksheet will update and change according to the workbook it references. 
Is there a way of making the v-look up work without manually hitting enter on the referred cells?

My Vlook up function is:

`VLOOKUP(B4,CAPA!A:AU,3,FALSE)`

To confirm - calculation in formulas is set to automatic.

With the additional requirement to implement 5 seconds after opening the document? I have added 
`Private Sub Workbook_Open(), 
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test"
End Sub`

However on running the code, an error displays stating the macro does not exist or macros have been disabled (to confirm macros are enabled and trusted)

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps try something like Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate?

Comment: Sorry perhaps I miss understand.. how would calculate format it in the required way ?

Comment: Think I might have a better answer, will post below

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Right, you might need to convert the imported data from text to columns. Bit of a shot in the dark, but if that's the case, replace the rngTargetCols below as relevant and this should work -

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngTargetCols As Range
    Set rngTargetCols = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:AU")
    Dim intIndex As Integer

    For intIndex = 1 To rngTargetCols.Columns.Count
        On Error Resume Next
        TextToColumnsFix rngTargetCols.Columns(intIndex)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

End Sub

Sub TextToColumnsFix(r As Range)

    With r
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Worksheet.Cells(1, .Column), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have implemented the code supplied (thank you), however can this be made to launch a few seconds after opening the document automatically? (please see comments above)

Comment: For 10 seconds wait add: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))